# Type alias not recognized using cheapskate in haskell

Tags: haskell, types, pandoc

### Summary:

I'm using [Cheapskate](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cheapskate-0.1.0.1) a library created by John MacFarlane, author of Pandoc, for markdown parsing. I'm running into a type issue that I cannot resolve. Basically I'm trying to generate the html for a code block. I ultimately want `renderBlocks def blocks` to type check. I cannot get blocks to be of type `Blocks`

In the source code, the type `Blocks` is aliased to `Seq Block` yet my error message says they are different. I've tried laying excessive type annotation throughout without luck. If I specify the type is `Blocks` as opposed to `Seq Block` I get an error specifying `Blocks` as `Seq a0`.

Here is my [project](https://github.com/cdosborn/lit-prog/blob/master/Processing.hs) for reference.

### The error message:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Blocks' with actual type `Seq Block'
In the second argument of `renderBlocks', namely `blocks'
In the expression: renderBlocks Cheapskate.def blocks
In the expression:
  let
    t = T.concat $ map partToText parts
    attr
      = CodeAttr {codeLang = (T.pack "haskell"), codeInfo = T.empty} ::
          CodeAttr
    block = CodeBlock attr t
    ....
  in renderBlocks Cheapskate.def blocks
```

### The code:

```
chunkToHtml :: Chunk -> Markup
chunkToHtml chunk =
    case chunk of
    Prose str -> toMarkup $ markdown Cheapskate.def (T.pack str)
    Def _ _ parts -> 
        let 
            t = T.concat $ map partToText parts
            attr = CodeAttr { codeLang=(T.pack "haskell"), codeInfo=T.empty} :: CodeAttr
            block = CodeBlock attr t
            blocks = (singleton block) :: Seq Block
        in 
            renderBlocks Cheapskate.def blocks
```

Comment: This could be something nasty about the `Seq` that Cheapskate refers to is different than the one you refer to, because you have two different versions of `containers` installed, your project depends on one, and Cheapskate depends on the other.

Comment: It looks like the latest version of conatiners, breaks that feature of cheapskate. Uninstalling my latest version (0.5.5.1) to (0.4.2.1) solved my issue. Thank you.

Comment: @cdosborn: If you have found a solution yourself, you should add this as an _answer_, not as an _edit_ to your own question.

Comment: @luqui If you want to post your answer, it should be rewarded. Otherwise, i'll answer it.

Answer (score 1):

Solution was to revert to older containers package from (0.5.5.1) to (0.4.2.1).